# safari cant open wallet pkpass file

Tags: c#, ios, passbook, wallet

I am currently working on wallet support for tickets and have been succesfully generating .pkpass (Passbook/Wallet) files for android wallets.

I am using the dotnes-passbook Nuget from Tomas McGuinness to create the .pkpass files.

The problem is that my .pkpass files dont work on the Apple wallet somehow. 
Everytime I try to open one on a Mac or on an iPhone it says that safari cant open this file. I hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong.

These are the .json files from within the .pkpass package:

The pass.json file:

```
{ "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.nl.lvpres",
  "formatVersion": 1,
  "serialNumber": "13843489004291",
  "description": "Dit ticket heeft geen beschrijving.",
  "organizationName": "LVPreserveringssystemen",
  "teamIdentifier": "M644RRJBDM",
  "sharingProhibited": false,
  "logoText": "Kamagura",
  "relevantDate": "2018-11-15T14:06:52+01:00",
  "maxDistance": "1000",
  "locations": [
    {
      "latitude": 51.9207297316102,
      "longitude": 4.4561515896691,
      "relevantText": "U bent dichtbij"
    }
  ],
  "foregroundColor": "rgb(238,238,238)",
  "backgroundColor": "rgb(255,255,255)",
  "labelColor": "rgb(170,170,170)",
  "expirationDate": "2018-12-30T00:00:00",
  "voided": false,
  "eventTicket": {
    "headerFields": [
      {
        "key": "date1",
        "label": "DATUM",
        "dateStyle": "PKDateStyleShort",
        "timeStyle": "PKDateStyleShort",
        "value": "2019-06-01T20:00Z"
      }
    ],
    "primaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "EventNaam",
        "label": "EVENT",
        "value": "Kamagura"
      }
    ],
    "secondaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "Locatie",
        "label": "LOCATIE",
        "value": "Theater Hanzehof"
      },
      {
        "key": "Plaats",
        "label": "PLAATS",
        "value": "Zutphen"
      },
      {
        "key": "Zaal",
        "label": "ZAAL",
        "value": "Theater Demo"
      }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "Rij",
        "label": "RIJ",
        "value": "5"
      },
      {
        "key": "Stoel",
        "label": "STOEL",
        "value": "7"
      },
      {
        "key": "Beschrijving",
        "label": "Beschrijving van de activiteit:",
        "value": "Dit ticket heeft geen beschrijving."
      }
    ],
    "backFields": [
      {
        "key": "keyb2",
        "label": "Over ons",
        "value": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      }
    ]
  },
  "barcode": {
    "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
    "message": "13843489004291",
    "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1"
  },
  "authenticationToken": "30246720af7f660136fd833f3886370b9995ba25",
  "webServiceURL": "https://secure.ticketunie.com/Wtickets/Tickets/"
}
```

And the manifest.json file:

```
{
  "pass.json": "c6b01b68b6a4fbada64c34cca61a7bfd181c5bd9",
  "icon.png": "993bcb011b93232db712724260b62d390d822fc6",
  "icon@2x.png": "993bcb011b93232db712724260b62d390d822fc6",
  "logo.png": "2e293ee364e5573bee329202b0996eacfcdb21b4",
  "logo@2x.png": "2e293ee364e5573bee329202b0996eacfcdb21b4",
  "thumbnail.png": "903b2fe6bd4cca1ecba481fea74be04e4231a640",
  "thumbnail@2x.png": "903b2fe6bd4cca1ecba481fea74be04e4231a640",
  "strip.png": "2e293ee364e5573bee329202b0996eacfcdb21b4",
  "strip@2x.png": "2e293ee364e5573bee329202b0996eacfcdb21b4"
}
```

Comment: You have `MaxDistance` as a string, you may also need to add seconds to your Data/Time value `"value": "2019-06-01T20:00Z"`  and a timezone to your expirationDate `2018-12-30T00:00:00`.

If the above doesn't fix things, can you post a link to your pass?  It could be a signing error, but won't be able to diagnose without examining the console when you try to load the pass on to a Mac or the iPhone.

Comment: Hello. I'm the creator of the library. As mentioned in the previous comment, it would be great if you could provide a sample pass.

Comment: @TomasMcGuinness and Passkit Thank you for helping, I have edited the dates and I can view the pass on a mac, but still unable to add it to an IOS wallet.   It is giving me the following error now on the console: The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified. I checked the pass using your passvalidator, The PassTypeIdentifier and TeamIdentifier are valid, so i guess its the certificate trust chain thats incorrect.  Here is the sample pass : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PoGJnDxF4UZ1-H-of3vt68URVBHVK0WQ

Comment: @TomasMcGuinness I have also tried to use actual DateTime objects in the dotnet-passbook library for the DateField and expirationdate but the library keeps translating those to an incorrect format, is there something i can do about it or do i have to use a standardfield as DateField to add it as string instead of DateTime. And with the expiration date I don't know what to do, since I can only add it as DateTime. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've had a few reports of the trust chain issue, so I'm looking into it. How did you create the pfx version of the pass type certificate? In terms of the DateTime objects, I have fixed this in code by changing to Offsets, but have not yet released an updated Nuget package.

Comment: I'm tracking this issue under https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook/issues/78

Comment: I am using a .p12 and not a .pfx certificate, could this be the issue? These are the steps i take from the command line using openssl to create a certSigningRequest:                             
openssl genrsa -out D:\www\certificates\Generated\%Input%privatekey.key 2048
openssl req -new -key D:\www\certificates\Generated\%Input%privatekey.key -out D:\www\certificates\Generated\%Input%.certSigningRequest -subj "/CN=LVP, C=NL"                                                                                                             
%Input% is the name i give them from the command line

Comment: And these are the Steps i take to create the .p12 from the .cer i get from apple:  openssl x509 -inform der -in D:\www\certificates\Generated\%Input%.cer -out D:\www\certificates\Generated\%Input%.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -out D:\www\certificates\Generated\%Input%.p12 -inkey D:\www\certificates\Generated\%Input%privatekey.key -in D:\www\certificates\Generated\%Input%.pem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with the certificate chain, it turns out i needed to export the apple WWDR as .pem instead of .cer.

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue! If you need any more help, let me know. I will add some tasks to add additional validation to my pass validator to try and catch issues with the WWDR and signing chain.